# I've disabled SSHD on my AWS instance. Any way I can re-enable it?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I have an AWS EC2 instance. I was trying lo lock down (chroot) an SFTP account to its home directory using [this guide](http://sites.google.com/site/bsdstuff/sftponly).  And I've managed to lock myself out of the server as I can no longer SSH in.  I don't think telnet is enable as I tried

```
telnet <ip address>
```

and received the message

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

So, given this, does anyone have any idea how else I may be able to connect to the server to re-enable SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't look to be anything in that guide that would cause you to become locked out if you followed it correctly. Perhaps sshd isn't running and so won't accept new connections, have you tried rebooting the instance ? If that doesn't work then you're probably out of luck as there is no recovery console for EC2 instances.

Comment: I tried a reboot, but no joy.  I think you're right about me not being able to get into it now.  Thanks!